# mat-slide toggle Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a panel and a list of checkbox inside it. When i open the slider, it should show the list inside the panel and when i close the slider, it closes all the list. But how can I save this event of the Slider-toggle, So that if make it open, it should save this event and when i come back and click on my panel, the slider shows as open. and if I make the slider close and come back later it should be close until i dont make it open.

HTML:

```js
<div class="panel panel-line panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Meb Katmanları</h3>
        <div class="panel-actions">
            <mat-slide-toggle color="warn" [(ngModel)]="allMebLayers" (change)="mebToggle()"></mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="allMebLayers" class="panel-body" style="max-height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto">

       
        
        <mat-selection-list *ngFor="let l of legends" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">

            <mat-checkbox>
                    <td class="p-5" style = "width : 90%" >{{l.layerName}}</td>

                    <td class="p-5"><img [src]="l.legend.imageData"></td>
            </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-selection-list>
        
            
    </div>
</div>
```

Component.ts :

```js
 change() {
        let mebLayers = this.layersOfMap[0];
        this.allMebLayers=true;
        
        this.mapService.syncFeature2Map();
    }

    mebToggle(){
        let mebLayers = this.layersOfMap[0];
        for (let m of mebLayers) this.allMebLayers ? m.visible = true : m.visible = false;
        this.mapService.syncFeature2Map();
```

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for general information about the slide toggle: to use it, you can bind the value of a slider to a variable in your typescript file

In your html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isActive" >Slide me!</mat-slide-toggle>
```

In your .ts file:

```
isActive: boolean;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        `<div class="panel panel-line panel-danger">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Meb Katmanları</h3>
                <div class="panel-actions">
                    <mat-slide-toggle color="warn" [checked]="checked" (ngModelChange)="toggle()"></mat-slide-toggle>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="checked" class="panel-body" style="max-height: 70vh; overflow-y: auto">



                <mat-selection-list *ngFor="let l of legends" style="overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x: hidden;">

                    <mat-checkbox>
                            <td class="p-5" style = "width : 90%" >{{l.layerName}}</td>

                            <td class="p-5"><img [src]="l.legend.imageData"></td>
                    </mat-checkbox>
                </mat-selection-list>


            </div>
        </div>`


    Component Code  

    `
    checked:boolean = false;

    toggle()
    {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
    }

    `
```

checked variable with save your last value of checked.....when u ll open this component again it will show this according to that